# Can you link part of the shape text of a shape in Visio to an excel spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, visio

I have a square shape with shape data that can link fine to an excel spreadsheet, but I also have some shape text that displays on the shape. I believe you can link all of the shape text by using the link wizard and selecting shape::text or something very similar.

Is there a way to only link a piece of the shape text though? I don't want my first line of shape text linked to excel. Only the second line. e.g.

---square shape beginning---

(Unlinked text here)

(linked text here)

---square shape end---

If not, I'll just link all of the shape text. Just wondering if there's a way to only link part of it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't link shape text. Only shape data. But later, you can use that data as a field in the text.

First, you link data to shapes. Then you can edit shapes to use the linked content as a field. Means, you start editing shape text, set cursor position to the place where you want your (linked text) to appear, then use "Insert Field", and select the linked text property.

Comment: Whoops, wrote this comment wrong last time. This youtube link shows someone linking shape text directly to excel data: youtube.com/watch?v=SuPzJ5g8Z0E. I'd like to do something like that if possible, but with only part of the shape text. If i can't, I guess I'll check how to set a field of shape data as part of the displayed shape text.

Comment: The video is about database wizard. That's a bit different. I thought you are talking about linking data to shapes ("Data" tab). Anyways, I've updated the answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft  is stingy and want you to upgrade your license so you can map external data to the shape text property . i wrote a little macro. this allows you to drag external data onto the Visio canvas and it will set the shape.Text. very simple, i use it to create uml class diagrams where i have lots of members i need to create. i load from an excel spreadsheet then i can drag and drop on to the canvas . remember to select the 'stencil control' before drag and dropping

```
Private Sub Document_ShapeAdded(ByVal Shape As IVShape)

    externalDataColumnName = "Prop._VisDM_FIELDLIST"
     'this is the property of the external data column header; look at shape sheet to get it

    If Shape.CellExists(externalDataColumnName, 1) Then
               
        Set celObj = Shape.Cells(externalDataColumnName)
        Shape.Text = celObj.ResultStr("")
        Shape.Cells("Char.Size").FormulaU = "8 pt"
        
    End If
End Sub
```